# How to check and cancel saving an image to file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, freepascal

I am using the [Vampyre Imaging Library](http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/) and it have a procedure to save an image to disk

```
 saveimage('c:\image\image1.png);
```

If the image to save is to big and the user want to cancle the saving proccesses, how can i check in the saving proccess is doing right now and how can i cancel the process...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This library does not offer any cancellation facility. I can see the following options:

1. Modify the source code of the library to allow cancellation.
2. Find a different library that does support cancellation.

Comment: David ... can you point me how to create a cancellation code in this library... thank you...

Comment: I'd pass in a callback function named `IsCancelled` which the save code can call repeatedly to check for cancellation. Then in the save code, check for cancellation at some suitable point. Inside one of the loops typically.